# Can you for loop through <li> elements and apply a mouseover function?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, onmouseover

Trying to make it so when you mouseover an item in the nav it becomes bold while hovering over. I know theres ways to do this in other languages but im trying to learn JS.

```
<body>
        <p>
        If you ask I will give you:
        </p>
        <ul id = 'nav_1'>
            <li>Some nice chocolate cake</li>
            <li>A fresh-brewed cup of coffee</li>
            <li>An honest compliment</li>
            <li>A brand new Porsche</li>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            "use strict";   
            const nav1 = document.getElementByID('nav_1');
            const listItems = nav1.getElementsByTagName("li");
            
            for(let i = 0;i<listItems.length;i++){
                listItems[i].onmouseover = function(){
                    document.listItems[i].style.fontWeight = "bold";
                }
                listItems[i].onmouseleave = function(){
                    document.listItems[i].style.fontWeight = "normal";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Hey Michael, if one of the answers below resolved your issue, please accept one of them to finish this question. Tahnk you!

Answer (score 2):

Hi Michael and welcome to StackOverflow.

For this I would recommend you use CSS instead of JS. It's easier and more efficient that way

```css
#nav_1 li:hover { /* Bold li element on hoverin nav_1 elements */
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    If you ask I will give you:
    </p>
    <ul id = 'nav_1'>
        <li>Some nice chocolate cake</li>
        <li>A fresh-brewed cup of coffee</li>
        <li>An honest compliment</li>
        <li>A brand new Porsche</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

This would be the JS solution. You problem is in the callback. `document` does not have a variable called `listItems` you might have mistaken it for `window`. There was also a typo in `getElementByID` it must be `getElementById`, JS functions are case sensitive.

```
<body>
    <p>
    If you ask I will give you:
    </p>
    <ul id = 'nav_1'>
        <li>Some nice chocolate cake</li>
        <li>A fresh-brewed cup of coffee</li>
        <li>An honest compliment</li>
        <li>A brand new Porsche</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        "use strict";
        const nav1 = document.getElementById('nav_1');
        const listItems = nav1.getElementsByTagName("li");

        for(let i = 0;i<listItems.length;i++){
            listItems[i].onmouseover = function(e){
                listItems[i].style.fontWeight = "bold";
            }
            listItems[i].onmouseleave = function(e){
                listItems[i].style.fontWeight = "normal";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

There was a minor typo on `getElementByID`, the last letter should be lowercase `d`.
Then remove `document` on the `listItems` variable.

As **Vitalij** pointed out, CSS would be a better route for the handling (no scripting would be needed), but keeping to the javascript:

```js
"use strict";

const nav1 = document.getElementById('nav_1');
const listItems = nav1.getElementsByTagName("li");

for(let i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++){
    listItems[i].onmouseover = function(){
       listItems[i].style.fontWeight = "bold";
    }
    listItems[i].onmouseleave = function(){
       listItems[i].style.fontWeight = "normal";
    }
}
```

```html
<p>
If you ask I will give you:
</p>
<ul id='nav_1'>
    <li>Some nice chocolate cake</li>
    <li>A fresh-brewed cup of coffee</li>
    <li>An honest compliment</li>
    <li>A brand new Porsche</li>
</ul>
```